# Parse a text file, if the content is a specific format print it

Tags: java

I have been trying to figure out how to parse a text file.  If the text file is not in a specific format than do not print the content.

The first line should start with an S, and every line is of one of the following forms

S:x

V:x

V:xxx

where x can be any upper-case letter, 0, or 1 or e.

here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;

class myjFileChooser {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final JFrame f = new JFrame("Document Viewer");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

            JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

            final JEditorPane document = new JEditorPane();
            gui.add(new JScrollPane(document), BorderLayout.CENTER);

            JButton open = new JButton("Open");
            open.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(f);
                    if (result==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                        try {
                            document.setPage(file.toURI().toURL());
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            gui.add(open, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            f.setContentPane(gui);
            f.pack();
            f.setSize(400,300);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
   }
 }
```

Comment: It is generally better to include the relevant code in your question, not at an external site.

Comment: you want to print the valid lines or if a single line is "invalid", don't print the whole content at all? and how big is your file?

Comment: Thanks Hunter.  I will remember that from now on.  I'd like to print the entire file if every line is valid.  If there is at least 1 invalid line then do not print.  The file is not large, at most 20 lines.

Comment: None of the code you've posted seems to be relevant to the task at hand. It's all the GUI code, and none of the business logic. What have you tried for the business logic part?

Comment: That is what I have been trying to figure out, the logic for parsing a text file.  I have not been able to find much for tutorials in my search so I resorted to posting here.  I apologize if the code for my GUI was not appropriate to post for this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to split your requirement into several parts.

First write a procedure `boolean checkFormat(String line)` which gets a line of text as input and returns `true` if it fullfills the needed format.

Second read the file line by line. 
Check for each line, if its format is ok or not by a call of your `checkFormat()` procedure. If not, then you are finished and you don't have to print anything.

Third, if all line checks were ok then read the file line by line a second time and print each line.

Here is an example to read a text file line by line: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Read_a_file_line_by_line#Java